# Can I wrap equations in BigDecimal?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

```
@amount ||= BigDecimal( @price * ( @tax_percentage / 100) ).round(2)
```

Is it ok to wrap an equation in `BigDecimal` like this? Or do I need to cast each individual component to `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to working with `float`, you need to cast one of the elements to `BigDecimal` to have the whole value return `BigDecimal`

```
@amount ||= (@price * ( BigDecimal(@tax_percentage) / 100) ).round(2)
```

In the sample above I've cast `@tax_percentage` to `BigDecimal` and not `@price`, since otherwise, if originally `@tax_percentage` was integer, dividing it by `100` will result in loss of data - the result would be integer...

```
5 / 100
# => 0

BigDecimal(5) / 100
# => 0.05
```

Comment: And (of course) for `a*b + c*d`, `a` or `b`, and `c` or `d`, must be converted.  Readers: note that `require 'bigdecimal'` is needed.